# Setting the Build Action for a folder in VS for a Win 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1, assets, buildaction

In previous Windows 8 /8.1 projects, any images that I have added to a folder inside the Assets folder is automatically set to "Content" in the Build Action.

[image: Build Action set to Content]

As a result, the images render when the project is built.

But our latest project seems to default to BundleResource, and after wasting time trying to work out why the image isn't rendering, I remember that I have to manually change each image to Content.

Does anyone know how to set the whole folder to Content so that newly added images will be Content by default? I don't know why this project is behaving differently to our previous ones. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue while ago. As far as I know is not possible to set Build Actions for folders on Visual Studio, only individual files.

The solution I've found is to edit `Project.projitems` manually (I mean, outside of VS and after it is closed, via another code editor) from:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Assets\example.json" />
  <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Assets\NestedFolder\example.file" />
</ItemGroup>
```

to this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Assets\**\*.*">
</ItemGroup>
```

Which will do the trick of setting everything under `Assets` as `Build Action: Content`, and will be able to see it mapped on Solution Explorer after restarting VS - or rebuilding files.

NOTE: Keep in mind that if you add anything to this folder via VS this rule could be overwritten. So, my advice is: once this rule is added, only add files directly to the folder.

Comment: Thanks Guilherme. I can't actually test this for the minute, as I am not working on Windows 8 at the moment. But in a couple of months time when I do get back to it, I will certainly give it a go.